# Rabl for a nested hash of ActiveRecord collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, rabl

I have a few `ActiveRecord` objects like `City`, `Country`, `State` etc. My controller action is like (as a representative example):

```
def get_data
  @data = {
    cities: City.limit(2),
    countries: Country.limit(2),
    states: State.limit(2),
    version: 1000
  }

  respond_with @data
end
```

I want to render a JSON like:

```
{
  data: {
    country: [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}],
    state: [{id: 1, name: 'p'}, {id: 2, name: 'q'}],
    city: [{id: 1, name: 'x'}, {id: 2, name: 'y'}],
    version: 1000
  }
}
```

(Please note singular keys for collections, Please do not suggest changes to the JSON structure, as it is fixed.)

What should be the `rabl` template for this? I have been breaking my head on this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

if i were you i will not even care to go to rabl template for this because what your are creating with this code:

```
@data = {
    cities: City.limit(2),
    countries: Country.limit(2),
    states: State.limit(2),
    version: 1000
}
```

is the final output , not the individual components.

you can just  replace this with:

```
render :json =>  { 
 :data => {
   cities: City.limit(2).map{ |c|{:id => c[:id] },
   countries: Country.limit(2).map{ |c|{:id => c[:id] },
   states: State.limit(2).map{ |c|{:id => c[:id] },
   version: 1000
   }
 }
```

its not a best use case for rabl , but if you still want it to load via rabl this below code in the get_data.json.rabl will do just  fine.

```
node :data do
 {
   :version_number => @data[:version_number],
   :country =>  @data[:countries].map{ |c|{:id => c[:id] , :name => c[:name]} }
   :state =>  @data[:states].map{ |s|{:id => s[:id] , :name => s[:name]} }
   :city =>  @data[:city].map{ |c|{:id => c[:id] , :name => c[:name]} }
 }
end
```